# Phonegap app issue : links within iframes take over the whole screen

Tags: iframe, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm building a phonegap app. It contains an iframe which loads the pages from another domain. Those pages may contain some links. When I open up those links on iOS, the links take over the whole screen. Then I have no way to go back to the application. On android, the link cannot be opened due to "Forbidden by X-Frame-options".  Any ideas how to fix it?  Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but maybe you will consider use `inappbrowser` instead of iframe. I just found it useful. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: The reason I use iframe is because I'd like to keep the header above the contents. I won't be able to keep the header if I use inappbrowser.